# Pandas excel like countifs of two dataframes with condition

Tags: python, excel, pandas

am hitting a block here. I have to translate this excel formula `IF(COUNTIFS(advisor!$C:$C,$A2)=0,"0 disclosed", "Independent")`

```
  if df.groupby('id').apply(lambda x: x['id'] == df_advisor['company_id']).count() == 0:
        df['auditor_compensation'] = '0 disclosed'
    else:
        df['auditor_compensation'] = 'Independent'
```

so far this is my python-pandas solution which i keep getting 
KeyError: ('company_id', 'occurred at index 1')

Any help will be very much appreciated.

**Edit**

**df** sample data: company data

```
id      ticker       iq_id     company              auditor_compensation
48299   ENXTAM:AALB  IQ881736   Aalberts Industries       ?
48752   ENXTAM:ABN   IQ1090191  ABN AMRO Group            ?
48865   ENXTAM:ACCEL IQ4492981  Accell Group              ?
49226   ENXTAM:AGN   IQ247906   AEGON                     ?
49503   ENXTAM:AD    IQ373545   Koninklijke               ?
```

below is **df_advisor** sample data

```
id    type          company_id  advisor_company_id
1     auditor       48299       60911
17    auditor       48752       165120
6359  auditor       48865       73607
37    auditor       49226       81877
4415  compensation  49226       90258
53    auditor       49503       81877
```

So the goal is to check the whole column `company_id` in `df_advisor`, and count the occurance `df['id']` in order to populate the `auditor_compensation` column.

Comment: Hi otje, welcome on SO. I hope you're going to find an answer for your question. It is a good idea to read something about [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and produce a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) [mcve2](http://matthewrocklin.com/blog/work/2018/02/28/minimal-bug-reports)

Comment: share sample data...

Comment: @I'-'I just added sample data, thanks in advance your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['auditor_compensation'] = np.where(df['id'].isin(df_advisor['company_id']),
                                      '0 disclosed', 
                                      'Independent')
print (df)
      id        ticker      iq_id              company auditor_compensation
0  48299   ENXTAM:AALB   IQ881736  Aalberts Industries          0 disclosed
1  48752    ENXTAM:ABN  IQ1090191       ABN AMRO Group          0 disclosed
2  48865  ENXTAM:ACCEL  IQ4492981         Accell Group          0 disclosed
3  49226    ENXTAM:AGN   IQ247906                AEGON          0 disclosed
4  49503     ENXTAM:AD   IQ373545          Koninklijke          0 disclosed
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to know if the name in the column A is in a list in the column C of your Excel.

```
df['Boolean'] = df['id'].isin(list(df_advisor['company_id'])
df['auditor_compensation'] = ''
df.loc[df['Boolean'] == False, 'auditor_compensation'] = '0 disclosed'
df.loc[df['Boolean'] == True, 'auditor_compensation'] = 'Independent'
```

Comment: solution is helpful but it doesnt take into account, the counting of how many times `df['id']` occurs in `df_advisor['company_id']` column